# select query is not worrking in my wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

my select query is not working in wordpress.that query is correct or not? how to solve this.

```
 $fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
 "
 SELECT a.vid,a.link, a.image,a.videoname,a.description,b.ID 
 FROM a." . $wpdb->prefix . "morevideos, b." . $wpdb->prefix . "posts
 WHERE a.activate_status=1");  

foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
$vid=$fivesdraft->vid;
$links=$fivesdraft->link;
$images=$fivesdraft->image;
$videoname=$fivesdraft->videoname;
$description=$fivesdraft->description;
$pageid=$fivesdraft->ID;
 echo $pageid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use eg. phpMyAdmin and check if that query return good data when sent directly into db, but I think your prefixes syntax is quite wrong. It should be:

```
SELECT a.vid,a.link, a.image,a.videoname,a.description,b.ID 
 FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "morevideos a, " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts b
 WHERE a.activate_status=1
```

Comment: you'r welcome. You should mark the answer as accepted when you think it's good answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you're not specifying the table names properly:

```
"SELECT a.vid,a.link, a.image,a.videoname,a.description,b.ID 
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "morevideos a, " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts b
WHERE a.activate_status=1"
```